# How to configure Varnish + Nginx reverse proxy on LAMP server

Tags: apache, nginx, varnish

I have already installed LAMP server on Ubuntu (digital ocean droplet). Now I want to install Varnish + Nginx reverse proxy on it.

I have only 1 GB ram on digital ocean droplet. So, Does  Varnish + Nginx + Apache is good or I should only install Nginx + Apache.

Actually website getting very good traffic. So I need to install Varnish, Nginx reverse proxy on the server for better performance.

Please guide me how can I configure this on the server.

Thanks

Comment: I am very new in hosting. So, I tried to install nginx+apache on my local system. But that has not worked

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you want to store in your cache and whether you need any complex conditions for caching rules (like caching based on some headers, cookies, IP address, etc.)

If you only want to cache static static content, then you can simply use https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/ and mount your cache folder as tmpfs (which is placed in RAM): https://blog.wp-rocket.me/mount-folder-ram/

Then you won't need varnish in front of nginx and will still have fast cache.